# Multiple Alerts in one view can not be called SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

The method of calling an alert in swiftUI is supposed to be simpler than ever, a simple example of this would be

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```

However, even though I am calling an alert and can verify the method is being called, my alert does not display.

In my code I have the following Struct

```swift
private struct resetButton: View {
    @State var isResetting = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Reset"){
            self.isResetting = true
        }.alert(isPresented: $isResetting) {
            print("We get here")
            return
                Alert(title: Text("Are you sure?"), message: Text("This will erase your Access Key."), primaryButton: .destructive(Text("Reset")) {
                    clearToken()
                    clearAccessKey()
                    clearUsername()
                    }, secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Cancel")))
        }
    }
}
```

Which is called in the main view simply by `resetButton()`.

However, when I push this button, despite `isResetting` equalling true, the alert does not display. I have verified that my `.alert` method is being called as the console prints

> we get here

the first time the button is pushed.

However, the Alert is never displayed.

An alert is displayed correctly elsewhere in this same view with

```swift
.alert(isPresented: $failedLogin) {
                        self.password = ""
                        return
                            Alert(title: Text("Invalid Login"), message: Text("Please verify your credentials and try again"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
                    }
```

When a `@State` variable named `failedLogin` is set true, however, the aforementioned alert is never presented.

My first impression is that this may be a bug in Swift, if it is I'll report it to apple. However, maybe something I'm doing isn't working because of an error on my part.

**Edit:**

As clarified in the answer below, the problem seems to be relating to the fact that my `resetButton()` was trying to throw up an alert in a view that already contains an alert. Apparently you can't have multiple alerts in one view.

Comment: Integrating your `resetButton` view into presented above `ContentView` I observe working both alerts, so probably the issue is in your main view.

Comment: have you got any solution of it. i am facing the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So i'm still not 100% sure why this was unable to post an alert this way? But I was able to fix this issue simply by placing the alert in the main view.

I changed the `@State` variable `isResetting` to a binding bool and paced a new state variable in the main class. I then just copied over the `.alert` and this seems to solve the issue.

The struct now looks like this

```swift
private struct resetButton: View {
    @Binding var isResetting: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Reset"){
            self.isResetting = true
        }

    }
}
```

and the alert is the same but is now in the class calling `resetButton()`.

**Edit:**

So it appears that SwiftUI won't let you call multiple alerts from the same view, however, if you want multiple alerts in the same view then there is a way around this.

You can call an alert from anywhere inside of a view so the following solution works.

```swift
private struct exampleAlert: View {
    @State var alert1 = false
    @State var alert2 = false

    var body: some View {
        Vstack{
           Button("alert 1"){
             self.alert1 = true
           }.alert(isPresented: $alert1) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("This alert can show"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
           Button("alert 2"){
             self.alert2 = true
           }.alert(isPresented: $alert2) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("This alert can also show"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
        }
    }
}
```

The catch is here that if either of these alerts were to be placed on the Vstack, one will not function. If they are placed on separate views though then both can be called as expected.

Perhaps this is something that will be rectified in a future update? In the meantime though, here is a solution for working around this problem.

Answer (score 24):

You can show alerts dynamically by using .alert(**item:**) instead .alert(**isPresented:**):

```
struct AlertItem: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: Text
    var message: Text?
    var dismissButton: Alert.Button?
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var alertItem: AlertItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("First Alert") {
                self.alertItem = AlertItem(title: Text("First Alert"), message: Text("Message"))
            }
            Button("Second Alert") {
                self.alertItem = AlertItem(title: Text("Second Alert"), message: nil, dismissButton: .cancel(Text("Some Cancel")))
            }
            Button("Third Alert") {
                self.alertItem = AlertItem(title: Text("Third Alert"))
            }
        }
        .alert(item: $alertItem) { alertItem in
            Alert(title: alertItem.title, message: alertItem.message, dismissButton: alertItem.dismissButton)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since only one alert modifier is need for a particular type of AlertItem ie. an Error alert vs Normal choice alert.

Comment: I need to use `isPresented` for viewModel binding... This doesn't work for that.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. Would be nice if Xcode can provide a warning about this or so.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it by adding an empty Text in front of the alert.

```
private struct exampleAlert: View {
    @State var alert1 = false
    @State var alert2 = false

    var body: some View {
        Vstack{
           Button("alert 1"){
             self.alert1 = true
           }
           Button("alert 2"){
             self.alert2 = true
           }
        }
           
        Vstack{
            Text("")
            .alert(isPresented: $alert1) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("This alert can show"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
            }
        
            Text("")
            .alert(isPresented: $alert2) {
                Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("This alert can also show"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
            }
        }
        
  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @aslebedev's answer, there needs to be an additional logic when using more complex buttons:

```
            .alert(item: $alertItem) { alertItem in
                if let primaryButton = alertItem.primaryButton, let secondaryButton = alertItem.secondaryButton {
                    return Alert(title: alertItem.title,
                                 message: alertItem.message,
                                 primaryButton: primaryButton,
                                 secondaryButton: secondaryButton)
                }
                if let dismissButton = alertItem.dismissButton {
                    return Alert(title: alertItem.title,
                                 message: alertItem.message,
                                 dismissButton: dismissButton)
                }
                return Alert(title: alertItem.title,
                             message: alertItem.message)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just sperate them into Enum cases

```
.alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
switch alertType {
case .wordIndex:
    return Alert(
        title: Text("Title"),
        message: nil,
        primaryButton: .default(Text("Continue")) {
        },
        secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Restart")) {
        
        }
    )

case .gameOver:
    return Alert(
        title: Text("Title"),
        message: nil,
        primaryButton: .default(Text("Main Menu")) {
            
        },
        secondaryButton: .cancel(Text("Restart")) {
          
        }
    )
    
case .endOfGame:
    return Alert(
        title: Text("Title"),
        message: nil,
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
            
        }
    )
}


enum AlertType {
    case wordIndex
    case gameOver
    case endOfGame
}
```