# Alert View - In a switch result

Tags: swiftui, alert

I have a button which creates a user when 'Sign Up' / Register is selected.

I have an error message show when there has been an issue with registration and this works successfully. Unfortunately, I want and need to alert the user that the account has been created successfully and to check their email for their verification.

The second alert shows for a split second then disappears, I'm not sure whether this is an issue with it being a second alert in the sequence. Do I need to create an enum, or will this not really matter?

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct SignUpView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    @State var user: UserViewModel = UserViewModel()
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var showError = false
    @State private var showVerifyEmail = false
    @State private var errorString = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Group {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TextField("Full Name", text: self.$user.fullname).autocapitalization(.words)
                        if !user.validNameText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validNameText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        TextField("Email Address", text: self.$user.email).autocapitalization(.none).keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                        if !user.validEmailAddressText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validEmailAddressText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        SecureField("Password", text: self.$user.password)
                        if !user.validPasswordText.isEmpty {
                            Text(user.validPasswordText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        SecureField("Confirm Password", text: self.$user.confirmPassword)
                        if !user.passwordsMatch(_confirmPW: user.confirmPassword) {
                            Text(user.validConfirmPasswordText).font(.caption).foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(width: 300)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                VStack(spacing: 20 ) {
                    Button(action: {
                        FBAuth.createUser(withEmail: self.user.email,
                                          name: self.user.fullname,
                                          password: self.user.password) { (result) in
                            switch result {
                            case .failure(let error):
                                self.errorString = error.localizedDescription
                                self.showError = true
                            case .success( _):
                                print("Account creation successful")
                            }
                            self.showVerifyEmail = true
                        }
                        
                    }) {
                        Text("Register")
                            .frame(width: 200)
                            .padding(.vertical, 15)
                            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .opacity(user.isSignInComplete ? 1 : 0.75)
                    }
                    .disabled(!user.isSignInComplete)
                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
            }.padding(.top)
                .alert(isPresented: $showError) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Error creating accout"), message: Text(self.errorString), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showVerifyEmail) {
                    Alert(title: Text("Email Sent"), message: Text("Verificiation email sent, please also check your spam"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Sign Up", displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button("Dismiss") {
                    self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                })
        }
    }
}

struct SignUpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUpView()
    }
}
```

I'm aware there is a lot of code missing to compile a complete view, but hopefully it can provide enough insight as to why the alert disappears.

Thank you all!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Alerts in one view can not be called SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116198/multiple-alerts-in-one-view-can-not-be-called-swiftui)

Comment: try separating ("attaching") the alerts to different Views. For example:
"attach" the `.alert(isPresented: $showVerifyEmail)` to 
the `Button`, and 
"attach" the other `.alert(isPresented: $showError)` to one of the `TextField` `VStack`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I’ve tried both, but doesn’t seem to solve the issue just yet, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting both showError and showVerifyEmail when you get an error. I assume you don't want to do that. So you might try this:

```
if !self.showError {
    self.showVerifyEmail = true
}
```